# Inserting all values of checked in the database

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have created so many check-boxes. ex:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_group[]" value="Pharmacist" /><span class="kassem">Pharmacist </span>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_group[]" value="Police Officer" /><span class="kassem">Police Officer </span>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_group[]" value="Pottery" /><span class="kassem">Pottery </span>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_group[]" value="Programming" /><span class="kassem">Programming </span>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_group[]" value="Puzzles" /><span class="kassem">Puzzles </span>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_group[]" value="Psychologist" /><span class="kassem">Psychologist </span>
```

Know the user is allowed to check as many as he wants. Know I knew how to echo the checked check-boxes using PHP. But I want to know how to connect it to a row in the database in phpmyadmin? Well I knew how but the database only inserts the value of the last checked element! I want it to insert all checked elements any help please? 

this is the php:

```html
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Accept" class="hassan" /><br /><br />
<?php
include "db.php";
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $optionArray = $_POST['chk_group'];
    for ($i=0; $i<count($optionArray); $i++) {
        echo "<div>" ."<span class='kassem'>" . $optionArray[$i]."<br />" . "<br />" . "</span>". "</div>";
   $hobby = $optionArray[$i];
   $sql = "UPDATE `login1` SET `hobby`='$hobby' WHERE `ID`='$id'";
   $res=mysql_query($sql);
   if($res) {
     echo "connected";
     } else {
     echo "bad";
   }
  }
   
    }

?>
```

Comment: Ihavenoideawhatyouretalkingabout.

Comment: Does anybody know what punctuation means?

Comment: Please improve your question adding your code to it!

Comment: okay I'll fix it please wait.

Comment: better or do you need more specification?

Comment: Nothing about the HTML can cause the problem you describe (although you should learn about the label element).

Comment: Yeah I know I just want to know the write syntax to add the checked values to the database all together at once.

Comment: Err. The same as for a single value, but with a `for` loop around the PHP statement that executes that prepared SQL statement (he said, making lots of assumptions about the PHP that is missing from the question and the database schema that is also missing from the question).

Comment: I tried setting the type of the row to enum but still it inserts the last checked value. The database won't add alz values at once how to do that?

Comment: There that's what I did using php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storying the hobby value in a column in the same table as the rest of the record. That can only hold a single value.

You should normalise your database.

Create another two tables.

- One to hold all the possible values of `hobby` (along with an id column for the primary key)
- A [junction table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) where two of the columns are foreign keys on the `hobby` table and the `login1` table.

Then INSERT a new entry in the junction table for each checked checkbox.

Comment: Okay thanks allot but I have question to understand.
first, on the first table I'll have 2 columns write? one for the id and the other for all possible values of the hobbies write? (Sorry for the question but I;am a beginner.)
second, login1 table I didn't understand whats the use of login1?

Comment: `login1` is the table you already have. Presumably it contains a bunch of data about a particular user. Look at the Wikipedia page on junction tables I linked to in the answer, it has diagrams.